# Run Python HTTPServer in Background windows 10 Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I have tested several proposal from anwers from other post but I can't get my server con run on the background from powershell using >pythonw server.py as I do with my other scrips.

my code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, test
import socketserver
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
import requests
import asyncio
import sys, os, signal, threading

class MyHttpRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers (self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

    def do_GET(self):

        self.send_response(200)

        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")

        self.end_headers()
        html = f"31"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(html, "utf8"))

def create_server():
    port = 8000
    handler_object = MyHttpRequestHandler
    my_server = socketserver.TCPServer(("", port), handler_object)

    print("serving at port:" + str(port))
    my_server.serve_forever()


threading.Thread(target=create_server).start()
```

the server runs just ok on foreground (calling it from PW >python server.py) but in background it does not reply.

Comment: I am not sure I am following here. How does your query have any relation to PowerShell? There is no PowerShell code in your post. You are running, python, and though you can call python, from PowerShell, you are still using Python and that process is controlled by Python, not PowerShell. You can use PowerShell background jobs as a potential solution to run your Python code. BTW, you can create a web server using PowerShell as well.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure it could easily be done using PowerShell as that is meant to be an interactive shell rather than a background system.

A couple of ideas. One is harder than the other.

1. Compile the python code into an EXE using something like [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) and then run the EXE as a Windows Service (which is difficult to do at best)
2. Set up a scheduled task that runs the python script using pythonw when you log in to the system. This option would probably be the easier of the two and could be done through PowerShell using [New-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps)

I suppose a third way would be through IIS but I’m not familiar with that unfortunately.

Edit: one other idea! Install Docker for Windows and run the server on a container rather than on your Windows host itself.

Comment: I do use powershell for my other python scripts using "pythonw script.py" but for some reason it does not work on this server as it stops running